# How to have dependent @RequestHeader in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How can I have dependent `@RequestHeader` in spring-boot application?

e.g. there are two request headers `RH1` and `RH2`(for example) where `RH1` is mandatory if you don't provide `RH2` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind both headers in your `RequestMapping` method but do not put `required = true`.
For example:

```
public ResponseEntity someMethod(@RequestHeader(value="RH1", required = false) String RH1, 
@RequestHeader(value="RH2", required = false) String RH2){
 // check which header is present and do your required logic
}
```

Comment: thanks it works but I have explicitly check for the headers. Would very much appreciate if you can suggest anything without doing any manual checks at code level.

Comment: @Suvy if this works you can accept the answer so that it can help others too in the community. I'll figure out if there is any code level way of doing this.